# What is the type you get when you call javax.mail.Message.getInputStream()

Tags: jakarta-mail

I am trying to parse an email then save the actual email as a file in the file system for auditing and remove it from the exchange server.   (same way like you do email save as in outlook)

So to do that I have found out that I can call

```
Message.getInputStream()
```

To retrieve the file bytes. Its working Ok, and I can write the email as a file to the file system.

my question is what is this file type? is it .eml or .msg? or something else?
when looking at its content I see text and not binary data

```
--_004_MWH_#TRUNCATED#_11namp_
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
boundary="_000_MWHPR_#TRUNCATED#_1711namp_"

--_000_MWHPR10_#TRUNCATED#_HPR10MB1711namp_
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
```

getInputStream doesn't say much about the type of data...
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/mail/Part.html#getInputStream--

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [getContentType](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/mail/Part.html#getContentType--) on the message.  Mime messages map to `.eml` on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Message.writeTo to save the message to a file.

Comment: same question to  writeTo method, what is the output file type?

Comment: It's a text file.  You can name it whatever you want, but a common filename extension used for MIME format files is ".eml".